# when does Windows Hosts file redirection take place

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, hosts

In regards to a browser http request life cycle, before the actual execution of sending the request, at what point does the, so to speak, "DNS" of the windows hosts file take place? After entering a site address into any web browser, when you hit enter, is one of the first things that takes place a check to the hosts file? or perhaps one of the last? Would a javascript chrome extension or firefox add-on be able to override what is in the hosts file at all? Is the point of execution browser dependant?

Comment: I've found I always needed to restart the browser for any changes in `hosts` to come into effect. Of course, it could depend on the TTL of the "true" DNS record - also, I don't think this is really on-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: Oh.. shoot. Where would be a good place to ask?

Comment: Not sure ... other stackexchange communities like https://superuser.com/ or maybe a networking one - search in the list https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Probably on [**SuperUserSE**](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: This is a development question for finding the timing of a browser request, to see if it is possible to change the resolved ip with a browser add on after the host file changes take effect. Does that make it relevant to stackexchange?